# Open Street Maps - using .osm file with GMap.net

Tags: google-maps

I have downloaded India.osm file. I have a windows application written in C#.net. I would like to use GMap.net to plot routes/pin heads etc using offline data from India.osm file. But I do not have any information on how to use GMap.net with .osm files. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need parse osm file and add routes/points/etc to the map